# Graphic noise in OSX

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, screen, gpu

I've been experiencing a strange thing in my MBP 2010 and only in OSX, haven't noticed this when I boot into Windows.

Noise happens for a second or two when changing state - loading pages, switching windows etc., this is the extreme occurence:

[image: noise]

Here is the [video of this](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/100j3k1S180U3u3j0b24/jitter.mp4.gif), but less extreme (the section above the edit box jitters).

What could be causing this? It seems to be getting more frequent...

Comment: It's probably a hardware problem. I've seen symptoms like this on a few different systems. It was fixed by taking it to Apple and getting the motherboard replaced. As for the cause, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm also thinking it could be, but I took it to the repair center and they ran some tests for GPU and it didn't report any problems... Also how come it doesn't happen in Windows? It could still be hardware but it's strange... :///

Comment: The best thing to do would be to boot from a separate partition or hard drive. If you don't have one available, the next best is create a fresh account on the machine. If it doesn't happen with either one of these, it's probably a corrupt file somewhere.  If it does happen, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's hardware either. Taking it to the Genius bar at an Apple store is your best bet for getting it fixed quickly.

Comment: I'm in Slovenia, it seems there are no Apple "Geniuses" here :( This guy just ran some tests and "didn't find the problem"... whatever. I'll try testing it with different accounts / installs then to know more about the issue myself.

Comment: Does the OSX upgrade (in a few months?) fix the possibly corrupt files?

Comment: That wouldn't be unheard of. You could try running Disk Utility's "Fix Permissions" for the disk in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to break the bad news, but your GPU has failed. [This is a known issue for your machine.](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-5681) Your model *was* subject to a replacement program for the logicboard due to a defective GPU, though it no longer is active. Apple may or may not still replace your logicboard. It is ultimately at the discretion of the store manager. If you don't qualify, your other option would be a flat rate repair, for ~$300, which Apple will repair anything wrong with the machine for this fee. Just googling around, [other options exist](https://www.macworld.com/article/2062783/cures-for-a-panicking-mid-2010-macbook-pro.html) that may prolong the life of your machine.

Ultimately though, this is a hardware issue for which no online troubleshooting exists. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, yes indeed it was a well known hardware fault... I tried correcting with used GPU once, but it was the same, I then finally bought a new Macbook because the older one was actually not adequate anymore even if it didn't have this GPU issue.